# number of galois extensions of local fields of fixed degree

Tags: nt.number-theory, class-field-theory

Let $K$ be a local field (of characteristic 0) with (finite) residue field of characteristic $l$ and let $p$ be a prime.

Considering the cases, whether the $p$-th roots of unity are in $K$ and whether $l$ equals $p$ (and maybe whether $p=2$) or not, my question is:

How many Galois extensions of $K$ of degree $p$ exist?

Comment: http://math.asu.edu/~jj/localfields/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $K$ contains the $p$-th roots of unity, then Kummer theory tells us that the degree $p$ Galois extensions of $K$ are in bijective correspondence with the subgroups of $K^{\times}/(K^{\times})^p$ of order $p$. The structure of $K^{\times}$ is well-known; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_fields or any decent book on local fields. So you can work out the answer in this case.

If $K$ doesn't contain the $p$-th roots of unity, then it becomes harder. Here are some special cases. For every $d \in \mathbb{N}$, $K$ has a unique unramified extension of degree $d$, which is necessarily cyclic - see Corollary 4.4 of these nice notes: http://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/algebra/localfields.pdf So in particular there is a unique unramified degree p Galois extension of $K$.

If $l \neq p$, then any ramified extension of $K$ must be totally and tamely ramified. But then by 5.3 and 5.4 of the above notes, $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ must embed into the unit group of the residue field of $K$. Then by Hensel's Lemma, $K$ must contain $p$-th roots of unity and so we are reduced to the Kummer case above.

So we are left with the case $l=p$ and $K$ not containing $p$-th roots of unity. I'll think about this some more, but you should be able to use class field theory as mentioned above.

Comment: Just for clarity (I just confused myself for a minute): What you are saying in your third paragraph is that *either* $K$ contains all $p$-th roots of unity (so we are in the Kummer case), *or* there are no ramified Galois extensions of degree $p$ at all (so the unramified is the only one).

Comment: Yes (assuming $l \neq p$, of course).

Answer (score 12):

I am sorry if I see this question only now, but since no one gave the following answer, it seems worth posting it.

There is a general formula for the number of extensions of degree $d$ of a $p$-adic field $K$ contained inside a fixed algebraic closure $\overline{K}$, which is given by
$$
\# \{ L \mid K \subseteq L \subseteq \overline{K}, \, [L \colon K] = d \} = \sigma(h) \cdot \sum_{j = 0}^m \frac{p^{m+j+1} - p^{2j}}{p - 1} \cdot (p^{\varepsilon_p(j) \cdot d \cdot d_0} - p^{\varepsilon_p(j - 1) \cdot d \cdot d_0})
$$
where:

- $\sigma$ denotes the [sum of divisors function](https://oeis.org/wiki/Sum_of_divisors_function);
- $h, m \in \mathbb{N}$ are the unique natural numbers such that $p \nmid h$ and $d = h \cdot p^m$;
- $\varepsilon_p(j) := \sum_{k=1}^j p^{-k}$ if $j \geq 1$, $\varepsilon_p(0) := 0$ and $\varepsilon_p(-1) := -\infty$, *i.e.* $p^{\varepsilon_p(-1) \cdot d} = 0$. In particular, $p^{\varepsilon_p(j) \cdot d} \in \mathbb{N}$ if $-1 \leq j \leq m$;
- $d_0 := [K \colon \mathbb{Q}_p]$.

This formula is due to Krasner, and has been proved in the paper "[Nombre des extensions d'un degré donné d'un corps $\mathfrak{p}$-adique](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~lorenz/KrasnerNombreExtensions.pdf)". The proof uses the same analytic techniques that go into the proof of the (much more famous) [Krasner lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krasner%27s_lemma).

Observe that this number is different from the number of *$K$-isomorphism classes* of extensions of $K$ having a given degree. This is of course due to the presence of non-Galois extensions. Here are two examples of this phenomenon:

- if $q \neq p$ is a prime then there are $q + 1$ fields $K \subseteq L \subseteq \overline{K}$ having degree $[L \colon K] = q$, but there are only two isomorphism classes of these fields: one containing the only unramified extension, and the other containing the tamely and totally ramified extensions;
- if $p \geq 3$ there are $1 + p + (p^2 - p) \cdot p$ extensions $\mathbb{Q}_p \subseteq L \subseteq \overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ such that $[L \colon \mathbb{Q}_p] = p$, but they form $1 + p + p^2 - p = p^2 + 1$ isomorphism classes. $p + 1$ of these contain a unique extension (which is Galois over $\mathbb{Q}_p$) and every other isomorphism class contains $p$ extensions (see for example Proposition 2.3.1 in the paper "[A database of local fields](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747717105001276)" by Jones and Roberts).

Finally, let me remark that this formula is related to Serre's "mass formula", which is valid in any characteristic. This formula says that a certain "count" of totally ramified extensions of a local, non-Archimedean field $K$ of degree $d$ is equal to $d$. More precisely,
$$
\sum_{L \in \Sigma_d} (\# \kappa)^{d - 1 - \mathrm{v}_K(\mathrm{disc}(L/K))} = d
$$
where $\Sigma_d$ denotes the set of totally ramified extensions of $K$ which have degree $d$, and $\kappa$ is the residue field of $K$. Observe that if $p \nmid d$ then the formula can be written simply as $\# \Sigma_d = d$.
Two useful references for this are:

- Serre's original paper "[Une 'formule de masse' pour les extensions totalement ramifiées de degré donné d'un corps local](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6234149b/f323.item)";
- Krasner's paper "[Remarques au sujet d'une note de J.-P. Serre...](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k9813511g/f215.item)", in which he reproves the formula using his methods.

Answer (score 9):

A Galois extension of degree $p$ has Galois group $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, so you are asking about abelian extensions of your local field.  Thus the answer to your question can be obtained explicitly via local class field theory -- you can get the needed results out of Serre's *Local Fields* or many other books.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a belated answer (I came across this question only today) which doesn't require anything more than Kummer theory --- or Artin-Schreier theory, if you want to allow $K$ to be a finite extension of ${\mathbf F}_l((t))$.  I will confine myself to the more interesting case of degree-$l$ extensions (where $l$ is the residual characteristic).

If $K$ contains a primitive $l$-th root of $1$, then there is a natural bijection between the set of degree-$l$ cyclic extensions of $K$ and the set of ${\mathbf F}_l$-lines in $K^\times/K^{\times l}$ (Kummer theory).  The structure of this filtered ${\mathbf F}_l$-space is completely known; see for example Section V of [arXiv:0711.3878](http://arxiv.org/abs/0711.3878) (where your $l$ is called $p$).

If $K$ does not contain a primitive $l$-th root $\zeta$ of $1$, then put $K'=K(\zeta)$, $\Delta={\rm Gal}(K'|K)$ and $\omega:\Delta\to{\mathbf F}_l^\times$ the cyclotomic character giving the action of $G$ on the $l$-th roots of $1$.  Then there is a natural bijection between the set of degree-$l$ cyclic extensions of $K$ and ${\mathbf F}_l$-lines in the $\omega$-eigenspace for the action of $\Delta$ on $K^{\prime\times}/K^{\prime\times l}$.  The structure of this filtered ${\mathbf F}_l[\Delta]$-module can be completely determined; see for example [arXiv:0912.2829](http://arxiv.org/abs/0912.2829).

If you are interested more generally in all degree-$l$ (separable) extensions of $K$ (and not just the cyclic ones), then something similar can be done.  Put $L=K(\root{l-1}\of{K^\times})$ and $G={\rm Gal}(L|K)$.  There is a natural bijection between the set of (isomorphism classes of) degree-$l$ (separable) extensions of $K$ and the set of $G$-stable lines in the ${\mathbf F}_l$-space $L^\times/L^{\times l}$.  Again, the structure of this filtered ${\mathbf F}_l[G]$-module is completely known: see for example
[arXiv:1005.2016](http://arxiv.org/abs/1005.2016).

Finally, if you allow $K$ to be a finite extension of ${\mathbf F}_l((t))$, there are similar results using Artin-Schreier theory instead of Kummer theory.  See for example [arXiv:0909.2541](http://arxiv.org/abs/0909.2541) for degree-$l$ cyclic extensions (which correspond to ${\mathbf F}_l$-lines in $K^+/\wp(K^+)$, where $\wp(x)=x^l-x$) and [arXiv:1005.2016](http://arxiv.org/abs/1005.2016)
for degree-$l$ separable extensions, which correspond to $G$-stable ${\mathbf F}_l$-lines in $L^+/\wp(L^+)$, where $L$ is still $K(\root{l-1}\of{K^\times})$ and $G={\rm Gal}(L|K)$.  The filtered ${\mathbf F}_l$-space (resp. ${\mathbf F}_l[G]$-module) $K^+/\wp(K^+)$ (resp. $L^+/\wp(L^+)$) has been completely determined therein. These results allow you in particular to count the number of extensions with bounded ramification, of which there are only finitely many.